# Changing the wheels on a hybrid giant escape

Tags: wheels

I have a spare set of Giant SR2 wheels lying around and I was thinking about buying a Giant Escape 3 and changing the wheels over.

Would there be any issue with doing this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It will work fine provided you put an appropriate speed cassette on it -- they have the same hub spacing, both are 700c and both ship with Shimano compatible freehubs (so you can indeed put an appropriate cassette on both of them).